# Share a variable between classes

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the same variable (a list) in different classes (this is a basic example of my code, but basically is the same functionality, get a list in Class1 and then use it in Class2):

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dosomething():
    def dosomething(self):
        x = [99, 98]
        return x

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        y = Class1()
        print y
```

But when I call Class2 instead print the `list [99, 98]`, I get something like this:

```
<myfile.Class1 instance at 0xb74c59ac>
```

Any idea if it is possible to share how to do it? I'm doing something wrong but I can't find in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because you haven't called the "dosomething" method form class1.

ACTUALLY i was wrong, you have, you just needed to call it self.x instead of x

ALso, you would want to call y.x to access the array, and instead of x =...you need self.x =, and it needs to go in the init.  I'll modify your code for you.

```
class Class1:
  def __init__(self):
    self.dosomething()
  def dosomething(self):
    self.x = [99, 98]


class Class2:
  def __init__(self):
    y = Class1()
    print y.x
```

I'd actually just recommend doing this for class1:

```
class Class1:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = [99, 98]
```

and for Class2:

```
class Class2:
  def __init__(self):
   self.y = Class1().x
```

Comment: I understand is called within __init__ ? If I make print x just before the return it print it correctly

Comment: do my edits make sense? I think what you want is for x to be a member of the class, in that case you need to use "self" to refer to it.

Comment: Also, something to remember, if you don't have a "self" prefix before anything you are working with in a class, it isn't a member of that class, and will disappear. For example, the way you have it now, the "y" in Class 2 will not be Callable outside of the class, but if you do self.y = Class1, then it will

Comment: And looking a little closer at the question you asked, it might actually  make sense to do y = Class1().x as your question was about sharing variables between classes.  That way, whenever you have a Class2, you can ensure that your y variable will be the same as the x variable in Class1().  See my update above

Comment: This is actually pretty bad practice, however...your variables could become out of sync if you change x in class 1 after you've called class2.  I'd echo zmo's suggestion and read up about a little more Python OOP. If the classes are pretty static after instantiation, then you're okay, but if they're changing a lot (the values in the array, you'll be hosed pretty quickly).  Another python idiom to consider is class inheritance:
http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

> *But when I call Class2 instead print the list [99, 98], i get something like this:*

this is actually what you shall expect. You're allocating `Class1()` and assigning it to `y` when you instanciate `Class2`.

now if you run the following code:

```
class Class1:
    def dosomething(self):
        x = [99, 98]
        return x

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        y = Class1()
        print y.dosomething()
```

you'll get:

```
>>> Class2()
[99, 98]
```

as output. Because you're instanciating `Class1`, and then calling the `dosomething()` on `y` and print the result.

Though, now, you have to understand that once `Class2()`'s constructor has finished executing, `y` does not exists anymore, as well as `x`. If you want to keep values, you need to use *member* of a class, which would look like:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [99, 98]

    def get_x(self):
        return self.x

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = Class1()

    def get_x(self):
        print self.y.get_x()
```

so then you can do:

```
>>> z = Class2()
>>> print(z.get_x())
[99, 98]
>>> print(z.get_x())
[99, 98]
```

where `[99, 98]` is the value contained in `self.x` of `Class1`.

I hope some things got a bit more clear, and it's time for you to open a book about OOP with Python, if that's what you're already doing, please read the next chapter! :-)

You have to understand that the whole point of classes in Object Oriented Programming is to actually **encapsulate** the data, exposing it through a **behavior**. So when you say you want to *share a variable from one class to the other*, there is something fundamentally wrong! That's why I'm showing you a way to exchange the data referenced by a variable between classes, without actually accessing a member of one class from the other.

> *Im doing something wrong but i cant find in the documentation.*

Thing is, it all depends on what you're really trying to do. And don't tell me you're trying to share a variable etc… It's only technical details. The real thing is the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Somewhat agree.  The beauty of python is that you can use it as an OOP language, or you cant.  Not so cut and dry like Java...

If you're writing something like an API, sure this is definitely what you want, but if you're writing backend code for an internal app...I make a case that you don't necessarily need it.

Comment: the OP is definitely a beginner, and the soonest he understands the basic concepts of OOP, the sooner he'll be at ease bending over them.